# How to create foundation popover nested with html content (template)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation, popover

I wanted to load a html template inside foundation popover, but i could not found any good documentation or similar solution on internet. I just wanted to know weather this is possible to have a html template along with its controller inside popover or not.
i saw we just load content in popover using properties like below:

```
<button popover="{{dynamicPopover}}"
  popover-title="{{dynamicPopoverTitle}}" class="button">Dynamic Popover</button>
```

or

```
<button popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="button">Mouseenter</button>
```

i can somehow inject the html using scope but difficult to have controller for that.

I want to load a popover for my website (which is getting build using angularJS) when user mouse over on video thumbnail i want to load the preview image of the video and on mouse over on popover i want to have some buttons which perform some action when click on them.

Comment: jsfiddle/plnkr please

Comment: This plnkr can be a good start. It has a popover and uses the above code. http://plnkr.co/edit/LdCOLnBK3itskjTJp037. It uses the angular native foundation directives project. How did you inject html into the popover? [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7zY2NMbMNrHMjNVCkuiR) (fixed from http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/#/tooltip, the native directives project), has html inside one of its tooltips, but if I follow you want the html inside the popover to interact with temaplate variables and not just show there?

Comment: @ matt: hi matt, thanks for your plnkr, i did not made it as i used nsPopover(https://github.com/nohros/nsPopover) which allow me to inject a template.

Answer (score 0):

Try This http://codepen.io/Blu-Jay/pen/wMRBLx

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
.callout{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.0.5/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.1.1/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 large-centered columns">
  <div class="callout">
  <h3>Password Verification</h3>
   <div class="row">
          <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="text-right">Username</label>
          </div>
          <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
        </div>
  
  <div class="row">
          <div class="small-3 columns">
            <label for="right-label" class="text-right">Password</label>
          </div>
          <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type="password" id="right-label" placeholder="Password Please" data-toggle="example-dropdown-1">
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="dropdown-pane" id="example-dropdown-1" data-dropdown data-hover="true">
        <strong>Password Must meet to following criteria:</strong>
        <ul class="no-bullet">
          <li style="color:red;">Must be between 4 and 8 characters</li>
          <li style="color:red;">Must contain capital letters</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```